# Valid JSON data cannot be parsed

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to JavaScript and I am stuck with this strange problem.
When I try to parse JSON data into a variable, the variable becomes undefined.

My code:

```
document.getElementById('searchPlayerForm').onsubmit = searchPlayer; 
        function searchPlayer() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            request.open(
                "GET", '${url}' + '/' + document.getElementById('playerId').value, true
            ); 
            request.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json');
            request.onload = responseAvailable; 
            request.send(); 
            return false; 
        }
        function responseAvailable() {
            switch (this.status) { 
            case 200:
alert(this.responseText); 
var playerResource = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
alert(playerResource.name);
...
```

The first alert returns:

```
{"playerID":49,"lastName":"XXX","firstName":"Walter","address":{"street":"XXX 2","city":"Eisden","postalCode":"3630"},"mobilePhone":"xxxx/xx.xx.87","phone":"xxx/xx.xx.39","email":"xxx.xxx@live.be","birthDate":"1948-10-11","rank":"D2","highestRank":"C6","memberSince":"1981","clubChampion":"1996","function":"Materiaalmeester","captain":"","linkVttl":"#http://competitie.vttl.be/index.php?menu=6&season=15&sel=14501&result=1&category=1#","currentMember":true,"currentIndex":10,"compNo":"507823"}
```

The second alert returns "Undefined".

Anyone who has a clue what might be the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Diher

Comment: Their is no name inside your json data. Try to alert(playerResource.lastName); it should work

Comment: I recommend using the developer tools included in your browser instead of `alert`. That way, you could troubleshoot your problems more effectively! In this case, you could quickly see that there is no `name` propery in the `playerResource` obj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no property `name` in the JSON

There is however a firstName, and lastName

To get full name, concat `playerResource.firstName` and `playerResource.lastName`

```
var name = playerResource.firstName + ' ' + playerResource.lastName;
alert(name);
```

To prevent issues like this in the future, you can always do a `console.log(playerResource)` to check what data you actually have. Or paste it to [JSONLint](http://pro.jsonlint.com)

Answer (score 1):

There's no `name` property in your json. There's `lastName` and `firstName` but no `name`.

Answer (score 1):

If you format the response, the answer becomes evident:

`{
    "playerID": 49,
    "lastName": "XXX",
    "firstName": "Walter",
    "address": {
        "street": "XXX 2",
        "city": "Eisden",
        "postalCode": "3630"
    },
    "mobilePhone": "xxxx/xx.xx.87",
    "phone": "xxx/xx.xx.39",
    "email": "xxx.xxx@live.be",
    "birthDate": "1948-10-11",
    "rank": "D2",
    "highestRank": "C6",
    "memberSince": "1981",
    "clubChampion": "1996",
    "function": "Materiaalmeester",
    "captain": "",
    "linkVttl": "#http://competitie.vttl.be/index.php?menu=6&season=15&sel=14501&result=1&category=1#",
    "currentMember": true,
    "currentIndex": 10,
    "compNo": "507823"
}`

As you see, there is no `name` key, so accessing `playerResource.name` will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `name` key. Therefore, `playerResource.name` is not defined. Try something like `playerResource.firstName + playerResource.lastName`.